# How to implement .NET database layer that maps queries to a single stored procedure?

Tags: c#, .net, database, linq

I have a database with a single point of entry - a stored procedure for issuing requests for example:

```
request("SELECT", "CLIENT", etc...)
```

The procedure is not defined yet but based on what my db guys tell me this is how it will probably look like. I will be able to pass action name (in this case SELECT), table name (in this case CLIENT) and will receive results in some form. (The reason behind this implementation is, as I understand, control over execution and reporting of the queries issued to the database)

I was wondering how to implement a db layer for such database?

I was thinking about implementing a custom Linq provider but maybe there's a better way / pattern?

Comment: Not your fault, but that's a horrible design.  What database are you connecting too?  Surely there is a better way to monitor the queries running against the DB than this.  How do they intend to implement Joins, GroupBy, Having clauses.  Oh, the mind boggles.

Comment: @pms1969 it will be an Oracle database. Just to prevent you from spending to much time on figuring out how to implement db better - I don't have control over it, I can suggest something but they don't need to listen.

Comment: Understood.  But I think you ought to try very, very, very hard to prevent them from doing what they are doing.  Oracle is an enterprise database that has all sorts of goodness in it for monitoring of queries and the like. I think your DBA's should be posting a question here on their design, and thinking around their decisions, rather than you trying out to figure the best way of dealing with the great big steaming pile of p** they've just dumped on you.  I don't think they'd last long.

Comment: A key question is: how do they think to return results? You'll need some standard output, but how would they squeeze all different entities into one generic definition? Or will they give you some list of large strings and a "good luck"?

Comment: If you don't succeed in twisting your DBAs's arms... A bit depending on how you receive your result, you may like [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive). It is designed to deal with flexible query output.